# C - Moving 2D array between functions

Tags: c

So basically, I am currently learning functions and pointers. I understand that I can't directly return an array from a function, and instead need to use pointers.

Form the code below, you can see that I am using the function `char * generate_2D_array( )` in order to create a 2D array. I am then looking for a way in which I can make this array work in my function called `Menu()`. My overall goal at this time is to then be able to print the `2D array`.

When I generate the 2D array and print it from within the same method, it works fine. I get a `12 x 12` grid of dots. However, with the code I have, I am getting a `12 x 12` grid of random characters and spaces. Please help me to fix this!

Current output is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVcO1.png)

Here is my code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

    int rand_num_gen( )
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        int randNum;
        randNum = (rand() % 12);
        printf("%d", randNum);
        return randNum;
    }

    char rand_char_gen( )
    {
        char randChar = ' ';
        int randNum = 0;   
        randNum = 26 * (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0));
        randNum = randNum + 97;
        randChar = (char) randNum; 
        return randChar;
    }


    char * generate_2D_array( )
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        char grid[12][12];
        char *p;
        p = *grid;
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0;i < 12; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 12; j++)
            {
                    grid[i][j] = '.'; //rand_char_gen( );
            }
        }
        return grid;
    }

    void print_array(char * array)
    {
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 12; j++)
            {
              printf("%c  ", *array++);
            }
            printf("\n\n");
        }    
    }



    Menu()
    {            
                char *myArray; 
                myArray = generate_2D_array( );
                print_array(myArray);

                printf("\nChoose a catagory: ");
                printf("\nPleease select your number of choice...");
                printf("\n1. Animals");
                printf("\n2. Colors");
                printf("\n3. Planets");
                printf("\n4. Weekdays");

                int valid = 0;
                while(valid == 0)
                {
                            printf("\n\nYour selection: ");
                            int catagory;
                            scanf("%d", &catagory);

                            if(catagory == 1)
                            {
                                        printf("\n\nPlaceholder\n");
                                        char word1[] = "dog";
                                        int length = sizeof(myArray);
                                        printf("myArray = %d", length);
                                        valid++;  
                            }
                            else if(catagory == 2)
                            {
                                        printf("\n\nPlaceholder\n");
                                        valid++;         
                            }
                            else if(catagory == 3)
                            {
                                        printf("\n\nPlaceholder\n");
                                        valid++;
                            }
                            else if(catagory == 4)
                            {
                                        printf("\n\nPlaceholder\n");
                                        valid++;
                            }
                            else if(catagory > 4)
                            {
                                        printf("\n\nInvalid input. Please select again.\n");                                    
                            }
                            else if(catagory < 1)
                            {
                                        printf("\n\nInvalid input. Please select again.\n");
                            }
                }                
    }
```

EDIT:
Okay so i fixed the issue. All i needed to do was make my array called Grid a static array. :)

Comment: Local variables are destroyed at the end of their scope.

Comment: Apart from the scoping issues, if it's a 2D array, what makes you think `char*` (for our purposes "an array of characters", but that's not technically correct if you consult a language laywer) is a good way to represent it?

Comment: @John3136 well it is, as long as you keep track of its dimensions as always.

Comment: @Quentin ... "as long as you" ... that's my point

Comment: @John3136 In C, you don't have any choice but to keep track. Or am I missing something? What do you suggest?

Comment: @PeterSchneider Use the correct type (or a typedef) `char*` is not a pointer to a 2D array.

Comment: @John3136 No, and I never said so. It's a pointer to an element in that array. That's fine. There's nothing wrong with it. The address of the 2d array can safely be cast to, and the elements of the array accessed through a pointer to the element type.

Comment: if all the warnings were enabled when compiling the code, then the compiler would have told you just what was wrong..  for instance: 'return grid;' is not a valid return type for char *'.  and 'returning address of local variable.' the return type from 'main()' needs to be 'int'   and 'unused variable 'char word1[] = "dog"'  and 'control reaches end of non-void function (main())'  You did not mention which compiler you are using, for gcc, use: -Wall -Wextra -pedantic

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are just that, local to the function they're defined in. That means when the function returns the variable doesn't exist any more. Returning and using a pointer to such a local (and non-existent) variable leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There are basically two solutions: Either create the array in the calling function, and pass a pointer to it as an argument; Or allocate the array dynamically off the heap and return that pointer.

---

Just a simple example, unrelated to your code, just to show you the principle:

```
void initialize_array_of_arrays(char (*arr)[],
                                      const size_t num_lines,
                                      const size_t num_cols)
{
    for (size_t line = 0; line < num_lines; ++line)
    {
        for (size_t col = 0; col < num_cols - 1; ++col)
        {
            arr[line][col] = 'A' + line;
        }
        arr[line][num_cols - 1] = '\0';  // Terminate as string
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char arr[12][5];
    initialize_array_of_arrays(arr, 12, 5);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 12; ++i)
        printf("Line %d: %s\n", i, arr[i]);
}
```

Expected output:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
EEEE
FFFF
GGGG
HHHH
IIII
JJJJ
KKKK
LLLL
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply! Do you think you could perhaps show me what you mean for the first solution? We havent been taught dynamic arrays so i think the second one will be beyond me

Comment: @Cookeymiceter Added some very simple example code to show the principle.

Comment: SO just to try and get my head around your first example, the first function is creating the 2D array? Im not to sure whats happening in the main function.

Comment: @Cookeymiceter No the first function only *initializes* the array, it's defined inside the `main` function and passed as an argument.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I solved my issue. I simply changed my array called grid from the function to a static array. :)

Comment: @Cookeymiceter, take care with `static` declarations: that means the array will be the same for every invocation of the function, so if you call the function a second time, it will modify and return the same array as the first time. That means you can't get two random arrays with different content by simply calling the function twice. For that, you would need to allocate the array dynamically (with malloc or one of its friends).

Comment: gcc -std=c99 -o arr arr.c
arr.c: In function ‘initialize_array_of_arrays’:
arr.c:11:13: error: invalid use of array with unspecified bounds
             arr[line][col] = 'A' + line;
             ^

Comment: I guess you must either work with fixed size sub arrays (#define the row size) or do what the OP wanted to do and simply iterate the matrix with a char ptr.